# TYPO3 7.6 Image rendering

Tags: typo3, image-rendering

After upgrading from 6.2 to 7.6 images are not properly rendered, I get incorrect images and the same everywhere when that shouldn't be the case.

```
description >
  description {
    10 = COA
   10 {
 wrap = <div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">|</div></div>
      1 = IMAGE
      1.file.import = uploads/pics/
      1.file.import.override.field = image
      1.file.maxW = 320
      1.params = class="img-responsive" style="max-width:100% !important"
      1.wrap = <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">|</div>
```

Found on some german forums that image rendering is possible in 7.6 just not sure what parameters have changed. Any ideas what's the proper way to render images on a 7.6?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when image rendering doesn't work as expected, I go to the Install-Tool, select the "Configuration Presets" menu item, and switch one of the image rendering presets (imagemagick/graphicksmagick) off and on again or select one that is green. After that I select "Clean Up" menu entry and clear all processed files.

Comment: Did that, doesn't help,

Answer (score 0):

Does the Test setup / Test ... images pass the tests? Are the images generating here properly?
If yes, try to remove everything from typo3temp and flush the sys_file_processedfile table (make a backup just in case) (Clean Up option not always helps and I had to do this manually)
If no, check the path to image magick binary (im_path), maybe it was overwritten on update. Check whether some custom settings and conditions was made in old localconf and lost during the update (typo3conf/localconf.obsolete)